# Column value changes based on anoother column's value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, scalability

I have the following Dataframe:

```
id questionCode answer difficulty
1  3t4          False   0
2  3t4          True    0
3  3t5          False   0
4  3t6          True    0
5  3t4          False   0
```

**I want the difficulty to change by one point based on how often the question was answered correctly or incorrectly.** The difficulty is already 0 (that is, very easy), and the question keeps being answered correctly, it can't go below 0.

So in this case, the output would be:

```
    id questionCode answer difficulty
    1  3t4          False   1
    2  3t4          True    1
    3  3t5          False   1
    4  3t6          True    0
    5  3t4          False   1
```

This is because `3t4` was answered one time correctly and two times incorrectly, `3t5` was answered one time incorrectly and `3t6` was answered one time correctly. Although not very elegant, the "final difficulty result" appears in every row once the code is done.

**The way I did it:**

```
import pandas as pd
testing = [[1,'3t4', False, 0],[2,'3t4', True, 0],[3,'3t5', False, 0], [4,'3t6', True, 0], [5,'3t4', False, 0]]
df_testing = pd.DataFrame(testing,columns=['id', 'questionCode', 'answer', 'difficulty'])
print (df_testing)
df_testing_update = df_testing.questionCode.map({'3t4':1, '3t5':1, '3t6':-1})
df_testing.difficulty = (df_testing.difficulty + df_testing_update).clip(lower=0)
df_testing_update
```

Output:

```
   id questionCode  answer  difficulty
0   1          3t4   False           0
1   2          3t4    True           0
2   3          3t5   False           0
3   4          3t6    True           0
4   5          3t4   False           0

0    1
1    1
2    1
3   -1
4    1
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I scale this when my data set is huge?
2. Is there any other approach, something like iterating over the rows and nesting if's?

Comment: `Is there any other approach, something like iterating over the rows and nesting if's?` If used this approach then solution is very slow. So cannot scaled in huge datasets.

Comment: I think solution is good, very nice scaled in huge datasets

Comment: @jezrael thank you. I just don't see how to translate it to bigger datasets. It's probably trivial but I can't figure out the syntax.

Comment: This question is not good fit for SO, move it to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. But it sounds to me like you want to:

1. map all the True answers to -1 and the Falses to 1
2. Sum up all the responses in each question code using a group by

```
df_testing['answerCode'] = df_testing['answer'].map(lambda x: 1 if x==False else -1)
df_testing['difficulty'] = df_testing.groupby('questionCode')['answerCode'].transform(lambda x: max(sum(x),0))
```